# How do I vertically align a theorem environment at the top?

Tags: vertical-alignment, theorems, amsthm

The following code renders the picture below.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{cancel}

% section
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{4}
% enumerate
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{align=left,leftmargin=*}
% theorems
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
% 2.4.3
\setcounter{enumi}{2}\item Each of the following derivations
proves a sequent. Write out the sequent that it proves.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumii}{1}\item
  \[
    \begin{prooftree}
      \Hypo{\phi}
      \Infer1[($\to I$)]{(\psi \to \phi)}
      \Infer1[($\to I$)]{(\phi \to (\psi \to \phi))}
    \end{prooftree}
  \]
  \begin{sol}
    \(\phi\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \phi))\)
  \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
% 2.4.4
\item Write out derivations to prove each of the following sequents.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \(\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \psi))\)
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{prooftree}
        \Hypo{\bcancel\phi^{\textcircled{\scriptsize 2}}}
        \Hypo{\cancel\psi^{\,\textcircled{\scriptsize 1}}}
        \Infer[left label=\textcircled{\scriptsize 1},
        right label=($\to$I)]1{(\psi \to \psi)}
        \Infer[left label=\textcircled{\scriptsize 2},
        right label=($\to$I)]2{(\phi \to (\psi \to \psi))}
      \end{prooftree}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution environment is vertically aligned at the vertical center of prooftree environment. How can I raise it to the top of the prooftree environment?

Comment: One way would be to put the tree in a parbox with the appropriate alignment. There might be a TikZ way, but i don't know TikZ.

Comment: How do I set parbox width to the maximum possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox`; I also made some other small changes (a command `\mathcircled` to avoid warnings, better labels).

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% section
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{4}
% enumerate
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{align=left,leftmargin=*}
% theorems
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\newcommand{\mathcircled}[1]{\mbox{\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
% 2.4.3
\setcounter{enumi}{2}\item Each of the following derivations
proves a sequent. Write out the sequent that it proves.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumii}{1}\item
  \[
    \begin{prooftree}
      \Hypo{\phi}
      \Infer1[($\to I$)]{(\psi \to \phi)}
      \Infer1[($\to I$)]{(\phi \to (\psi \to \phi))}
    \end{prooftree}
  \]
  \begin{sol}
    \(\phi\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \phi))\)
  \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
% 2.4.4
\item Write out derivations to prove each of the following sequents.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \(\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \psi))\)
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
      \begin{prooftree}
        \Hypo{\bcancel\phi^{\mathcircled{2}}}
        \Hypo{\cancel\psi^{\,\mathcircled{1}}}
        \Infer[left label=\mathcircled{1},
        right label=$(\to I)$]1{(\psi \to \psi)}
        \Infer[left label=\mathcircled{2},
        right label=$(\to I)$]2{(\phi \to (\psi \to \psi))}
      \end{prooftree}
      \end{adjustbox}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]